# What's causing play protect to warn me concerning apps behavior?

Tags: android, google-play-protect

I have an issue with apps internally deployed in my company.
Since the begining of the year, the Google Play Protect warns me that these apps are unsafe and try to steal my data. 
I don't have any clue on what's causing this issue.

Could you help?

The full message :

```
Blocked by Play Protect

This app is fake. It tries to take over your device or steal your data.

Details =>

Ever if you have heard of this app or the app developer, it's still dangerous to install an app from an untrusted source.
```

Comment: Post the full warning

Comment: I've added the full message

Comment: did you fix this issue ??

Comment: I didn't. According to Google, there was a malicious script in the apps generated by AppsGeyser. 
They couldn't give me more explanations.